# How to test ControllValueAccessor in Angular2

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular2-testing

I am writing Karma tests for my angular application. I use custom form controlls that are created with the ControllValueAccessor.

Is there a way to test the implemented ControllValueAccessor methods (registerOnChange, ...)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-form-input',
    templateUrl: 'input.html',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class InputComponent extends InputAbstractComponent {
    @Input() showPlaceHolder: Boolean = true;
    value = undefined;

    onChange = (value: string) => {
    };
    onTouched = (touched: boolean) => {
    };

    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    }

    writeValue(value: string): void {
        this.value = value;
    }

    updateValue(value: string): void {
        this.onTouched(true);
        this.onChange(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Test it as you would do with a component you didn't write: by using your component in a form, and checking it behaves correctly: does it update the model when you enter something in it? Does it display the value set programmatically? Does it become visually disabled when you disable the form control? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some test components in your `.spec.ts` file that have your `my-form-input` component in their templates. Have a look at [Angular Material Checkbox tests](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material-experimental/mdc-checkbox/checkbox.spec.ts) to see an example of this (you could also add `form` element to the test components)

Once you've created the component via the `TestBed`, and have access to the underlying `nativeElement` of the `DebugElement`, you can use the DOM `dispatchEvent()` function to trigger custom events such as `MouseEvent` or `KeyboarEvent` - Netanel Basal (one of the most thorough authors of Angular documentation) has a [good example](https://netbasal.com/simulating-events-in-angular-unit-tests-5482618cd6c6)

To check that your functions have been called, you would use Jasmine `spyOn` applied to the component instance methods